# ¿Como crear una zona en GPS y verificar cuando un celular este dentro de la zona?

Tags: phonegap

que tal?
Como dice el titulo, alguien tiene idea de como crear una zona en gps que verifique cuando un celular con gps activo este dentro de la misma?
La tecnología que manejo es Phonegap, cualquier idea me sera de gran ayuda.
Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Me pareció bastante interesante la pregunta y he encontrado una muy buena solución a su problema.

Según [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8531127/revisions), se puede crear un rectángulo o circulo(radio), al rededor de un determinado geolocalizar usando `contains` y `LatLngBounds`, así:

Incrustar [ApiGoogleMaps](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry&.js).

```js
var Vienna = new google.maps.LatLng(48.2081743, 16.3738189),
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: Vienna,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

      panControl: false,
      zoomControl: false,
      scaleControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      overviewMapControl: false
    }
  ),
  markerCenter = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: Vienna
  }),
  markerAPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(48.23, 16.35),
  markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: markerAPosition
  }),
  markerBPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(48.21, 16.36),
  markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: markerBPosition
  }),
  markerCPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(48.222, 16.35),
  markerC = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: markerCPosition
  }),
  rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0099',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#EE0990',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(48.226, 16.347),
      new google.maps.LatLng(48.19, 16.401)
    )
  }),
  rectangleBounds = rectangle.getBounds(),
  circleRadius = 2000, // Unit: meters
  circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    center: Vienna,
    radius: circleRadius,
    strokeColor: '#FF0099',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#009ee0',
    fillOpacity: 0.2
  }),
  circleBounds = circle.getBounds(),
  /**
   * Tests:
   * M*CB = Marker n Circle Bounds
   * M*RB = Marker n Rectange Bounds
   * M*SB = Marker n Spherical Bounds
   */
  // Marker A
  MACB = circleBounds.contains(markerAPosition),
  MARB = rectangleBounds.contains(markerAPosition),
  MASB = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(Vienna, markerAPosition) <= circleRadius,
  // Marker B
  MBCB = circleBounds.contains(markerBPosition),
  MBRB = rectangleBounds.contains(markerBPosition),
  MBSB = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(Vienna, markerBPosition) <= circleRadius,
  // Marker C
  MCCB = circleBounds.contains(markerCPosition),
  MCRB = rectangleBounds.contains(markerCPosition),
  MCSB = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(Vienna, markerCPosition) <= circleRadius;

// Proof, that google Maps API still can't handle "contains" for their paths elements.
console.table([{
    Type: "Circle Bounds",
    MarkerA: MACB,
    MarkerB: MBCB,
    MarkerC: MCCB
  },
  {
    Type: "Rectangle Bounds",
    MarkerA: MARB,
    MarkerB: MBRB,
    MarkerC: MCRB
  },
  {
    Type: "Spherical Distance",
    MarkerA: MASB,
    MarkerB: MBSB,
    MarkerC: MCSB
  },
]);
```

```css
html, body, #map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Referencia a Google Maps Geometry -->
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry&.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="map"></div>
```

[Demo](http://demo.developerextensions.com/answers/find-location-cordinates-in-given-radius.html)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Ejemplo funcional explicado](http://unserkaiser.com/blog/2011/12/16/google-maps-marker-check-if-in-circle/)

[Ejemplo en jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/kaiser/Hhb5M/)